# Page admins as admin of app?

Tags: facebook, admin, facebook-apps, facebook-page, facebook-comments

I have a Facebook Application in order to manage comments on my web page, allowing for moderation, etc.

I also have a Facebook Page, for the same brand.

Is there anyway of having an Administrator list that is shared between these two objects?  So that I can add and remove users from one and they would get/lose access to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this automatically, but you can:

- Have a trusted user (admin of the page and app) grant `manage_pages` permission to [your/an] app
- Get the page access token for managing the page - see "Page Login" on [this document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)
- Retrieve a list of the other page admins from `/PAGE_ID/admins`
- Use the [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin) to add those users as developers/admins/etc of the App by posting to the [Application's 'Roles' connection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#roles)
- Those users will receive (and must accept) a request to become an admin/developer/etc of the app

Caveat: the users you try to add to the app must be verified accounts (via SMS or credit card) or they can't be ad admin or developer of the app

Comment: Thanks Igy.  Sounds more complex than I was hoping for, but it does sound like the only way to do it presently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm NOT sure about this, but I never saw such thing available. Probably you'll have to integrate an application to your page that works on this